# Changing toolbar background alpha value when scrolling with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout, androiddesignsupport

I am currently trying to use the `CoordinatorLayout` class to adapt a `Toolbar` opacity depending on a `ScrollView` scroll position. I succeed doing this "manually linking" the two views, listening to the `ScrollView` scroll events and reporting them on the alpha value of my `Toolbar` background.

The wanted behavior is :

> The toolbar is starting in a **transparent** state (both text and background) and end up totally **white background** and **black text** when one view is totally scrolled.

The behavior is roughly this one : [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kh4UzOK6oKw).

**Current implementation**

*layout file (simplified)*

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <my.package.widgets.DetailsTop
                android:id="@+id/layout_details_top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <my.package.widgets.DetailsBottom
                android:id="@+id/layout_details_bottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*Fragment implementation*

```java
public class SearchVehicleDetailsFragment extends BaseFragment<SearchContract.ParentView> {

    @Bind(R.id.layout_details_top) DetailsTop detailsTopLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.layout_details_bottom) DetailsBottom detailsBottomLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.scrollView) ScrollView scrollView;
    @Bind(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                float alpha = (float) scrollView.getScrollY() / vehicleDetailsTopLayout.getHeight();
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getColorWithAlpha(alpha, getResources().getColor(R.color.white)));
                toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getColorWithAlpha(alpha, getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_grey)));
            }
        });
    }

    public static int getColorWithAlpha(float alpha, int baseColor) {
        int a = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, (int) (alpha * 255))) << 24;
        int rgb = 0x00ffffff & baseColor;
        return a + rgb;
    }
}
```

**Problem**

However, even if the previous snippets are a particularly simple solution that seems to work perfectly, I am just a little confused about why it didn't work with `CoordinatorLayout`. Also, I found a guy who seems to have succeed on this task with a custom `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` implementation.

You can take a look at his [custom CoordinatorLayout.Behavior implementation](https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/e587669f3d9b1519bc5e). He also gives some details on [Medium](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/1-20f-behaviors-of-alpha-6f506c9cb6a7#.9cxbpwsmu). However, due to a lot of just `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar   .../>` instead of the full `Toolbar` tag and a strong lack of understanding of how this part of the Support Design library works, I was never able to implement it...

**Question**

I would like to understand how `CoordinatorLayout`, and all the classes around it, works together. So I will probably be able to implement the behavior I am looking for, which is : linking a ScrollView scroll position to the alpha value of a toolbar background color.

Obviously, if you also know how to implement all this, I will be really happy to see your snippet :)

Comment: it looks like a cool concept nice one bro

Comment: If you're looking for a detailed explanation of coordinatorlayouts, check this out. https://medium.com/google-developers/intercepting-everything-with-coordinatorlayout-behaviors-8c6adc140c26#.nvsysrem6

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting with behaviors, I am happy you found my article partially helpful.

I redacted the code of the `Toolbar` chunk because it wasn't important. Simple `Toolbar` attributes, nothing special about it:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   app:layout_behavior=".view.ToolbarBackgroundAlphaBehavior"/>
```

> I would like to understand how CoordinatorLayout, and all the classes
>   around it, works together. So I will probably be able to implement the
>   behavior I am looking for, which is : linking a ScrollView scroll
>   position to the alpha value of a toolbar background color.

In your layout you are missing the `CoordinatorLayout` as being top parent that wraps everything. Instead of using `ScrollView` you should use `NestedScrollView` it works just like `ScrollView` but the difference is that `NestedScrollView` can perform nested scrolls in older version, unlike `ScrollView` which nested scrolls only after API 23.

For a `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` to work ***the target view must be direct descendant of the `CoordinatorLayout`***. As you can see in the article, the `Toolbar` is direct descendant of the coordinator. Otherwise, the behavior will not work.

In the example `NestedScrollView` has appbar layout behavior, so that `AppBarLayout` can expand and collapse, you can find plenty of examples about this.

Comment: Please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460263/toolbaralphascrollbehavior-coordinatorlayout